# Debugging linux kernel, SIGKILL

Tags: linux, kernel, debug, gdb

Trying to debug linux kernel (vmlinux) with gdb during my education, but after I run kernel I just got "program terminated with SIGKILL":

```
gdb vmlinux-3.11.0-12-generic
...GDB header...
Reading symbols from ....
(gdb) break start_kernel
(gdb) break init/main.c:1
(gdb) run
Starting program: .../vmlinux...
During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
```

OS - Ubuntu, Kernel - 3.11.0-12-generic with debug symbols, gdb - 7.6.1-ubuntu, under VirtualBox.